# Getting error on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting these error messages one after the other every week on Win 2008 and SQL 2008 R2. MAX DOP is set at 1.  Any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks.

> DESCRIPTION:   A fatal error occurred while reading the input stream
>   from the network. The session will be terminated (input error: 64,
>   output error: 0).  DESCRIPTION:   The client was unable to reuse a
>   session with SPID 60, which had been reset for connection pooling. The
>   failure ID is 29. This error may have been caused by an earlier
>   operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations
>   immediately before this error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you are running the newest builds this should be fixed by applying the [latest CU](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/540092/sql-server-2008-sp1-cu6-periodically-does-not-accept-connections) (look down in the comments).  Based on this bug/fix it appears to be a problem the CLR garbage collector.

Comment: Cool, Thank you Denny! It is always an honor to get your response.

Comment: Then mark his answer as THE answer :-). You should see a check mark near the answer.